# Keyboard shortcut to comment code in Thonny IDE

Tags: python, thonny

Whats is the keyboard short cut to comment single line of code and slsected lines of code in Thony IDE for python?
Ie, The Thony equivalent of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> in VS Code

Answer (score 3):

**To comment single line:**
Put a cursor on the line which you want to comment. Press Alt+3 to comment, Alt+4 to un-comment.

**To comment single line:**
Select the desired lines of code to comment. Follow same keys i.e. press Alt+3 to comment, Alt+4 to un-comment.

**Note:**
For further shortcuts, please click on Edit menu option next to File and you'd see various shortcuts available in Thonny IDE.

Comment: Murtaza Haji can you please check?

Comment: You have two " To comment single line" entries. I assume you meant " To comment multiple lines"

Answer (score 1):

Single line comment.`Ctrl + 1`.
Multi-line comment select the lines to be commented. `Ctrl + 4`.
Unblock Multi-line comment. `Ctrl + 5`.

Comment: Doesnt work on Thonny 3.3.3 
Linux 
Python 3.7.3(32-bit)
Tk 8.6.9

Comment: ohk let me check

Comment: Were you able to check?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ctrl+3` for toggling between "commented" and "uncommented".

Use `Alt+3` to comment.
Use `Alt+4` to uncommment.

[(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2gZd.png)

If you want to change the default shortcuts, you can follow the instructions on this official github-page:
https://github.com/thonny/thonny/wiki/Custom-shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

With the latest update of Thonny IDE you can do

```
ctrl + 3
```

for both single line and multiline commenting and uncommenting.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac and the most recent version of Thonny,

```
command+3
```

3 being the key with the # hash key above it. Works on single line and multi-select.